# incorrect string formatted as a percentage

Tags: visual-studio

Assume that numQuestions and numCorrect are variables  that has been given values. Write a sequence of statements that assigns to the string percentIncorrect a string formatted as a percentage indicating the percentage of INCORRECT questions correct to two decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

```
percentIncorrect = ((numQuestions - numCorrect) / numQuestions).ToString("p2")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it as well but couldn't get the right answer I know you want a visual basic statement. This is what I have so far.
percentInCorrect = (numCorrect/numQuestions ).ToString("p")